# heimdal kerberos in openldap issue

Tags: authentication, openldap, kerberos, sasl, heimdal

I think I posted this on the wrong 'sister site', so here it is.

I'm having a bit of trouble getting Kerberos (Heimdal version) to work nicely with OpenLDAP. The kerberos database is being stored in LDAP itself. The KDC uses SASL EXTERNAL authentication as *root* to access the container ou.

I created the database in LDAP fine using `kadmin -l`, but it won't let me use kadmin without the -l flag:

```
root@rds0:~# kadmin -l
kadmin> list *
krbtgt/REALM
kadmin/changepw
kadmin/admin
changepw/kerberos
kadmin/hprop
WELLKNOWN/ANONYMOUS
WELLKNOWN/org.h5l.fast-cookie@WELLKNOWN:ORG.H5L
default
brian.empson
brian.empson/admin
host/rds0.example.net
ldap/rds0.example.net
host/localhost
kadmin> exit
root@rds0:~# kadmin
kadmin> list *
brian.empson/admin@REALM's Password:      <----- With right password
kadmin: kadm5_get_principals: Key table entry not found
kadmin> list *
brian.empson/admin@REALM's Password:       <------ With wrong password
kadmin: kadm5_get_principals: Already tried ENC-TS-info, looping
kadmin>
```

I can get tickets without a problem:

```
root@rds0:~# klist
Credentials cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_0
        Principal: brian.empson@REALM

  Issued                Expires               Principal
Nov 11 14:14:40 2012  Nov 12 00:14:37 2012  krbtgt/REALM@REALM
Nov 11 14:40:35 2012  Nov 12 00:14:37 2012  ldap/rds0.example.net@REALM
```

But I can't seem to change my own password without `kadmin -l`:

```
root@rds0:~# kpasswd
brian.empson@REALM's Password:      <---- Right password
New password:
Verify password - New password:
Auth error : Authentication failed
root@rds0:~# kpasswd
brian.empson@REALM's Password:       <---- Wrong password
kpasswd: krb5_get_init_creds: Already tried ENC-TS-info, looping
```

kadmin's logs are not helpful at all:

```
2012-11-11T13:48:33 krb5_recvauth: Key table entry not found
2012-11-11T13:51:18 krb5_recvauth: Key table entry not found
2012-11-11T13:53:02 krb5_recvauth: Key table entry not found
2012-11-11T14:16:34 krb5_recvauth: Key table entry not found
2012-11-11T14:20:24 krb5_recvauth: Key table entry not found
2012-11-11T14:20:44 krb5_recvauth: Key table entry not found
2012-11-11T14:21:29 krb5_recvauth: Key table entry not found
2012-11-11T14:21:46 krb5_recvauth: Key table entry not found
2012-11-11T14:23:09 krb5_recvauth: Key table entry not found
2012-11-11T14:45:39 krb5_recvauth: Key table entry not found
```

The KDC reports that both accounts succeed in authenticating:

```
2012-11-11T14:48:03 AS-REQ brian.empson@REALM from IPv4:192.168.72.10 for kadmin/changepw@REALM
2012-11-11T14:48:03 Client sent patypes: REQ-ENC-PA-REP
2012-11-11T14:48:03 Looking for PK-INIT(ietf) pa-data -- brian.empson@REALM
2012-11-11T14:48:03 Looking for PK-INIT(win2k) pa-data -- brian.empson@REALM
2012-11-11T14:48:03 Looking for ENC-TS pa-data -- brian.empson@REALM
2012-11-11T14:48:03 Need to use PA-ENC-TIMESTAMP/PA-PK-AS-REQ
2012-11-11T14:48:03 sending 294 bytes to IPv4:192.168.72.10
2012-11-11T14:48:03 AS-REQ brian.empson@REALM from IPv4:192.168.72.10 for kadmin/changepw@REALM
2012-11-11T14:48:03 Client sent patypes: ENC-TS, REQ-ENC-PA-REP
2012-11-11T14:48:03 Looking for PK-INIT(ietf) pa-data -- brian.empson@REALM
2012-11-11T14:48:03 Looking for PK-INIT(win2k) pa-data -- brian.empson@REALM
2012-11-11T14:48:03 Looking for ENC-TS pa-data -- brian.empson@REALM
2012-11-11T14:48:03 ENC-TS Pre-authentication succeeded -- brian.empson@REALM using aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96
2012-11-11T14:48:03 ENC-TS pre-authentication succeeded -- brian.empson@REALM
2012-11-11T14:48:03 AS-REQ authtime: 2012-11-11T14:48:03 starttime: unset endtime: 2012-11-11T14:53:00 renew till: unset
2012-11-11T14:48:03 Client supported enctypes: aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96, aes128-cts-hmac-sha1-96, des3-cbc-sha1, arcfour-hmac-md5, using aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96/aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96
2012-11-11T14:48:03 sending 704 bytes to IPv4:192.168.72.10

2012-11-11T14:45:39 AS-REQ brian.empson/admin@REALM from IPv4:192.168.72.10 for kadmin/admin@REALM
2012-11-11T14:45:39 Client sent patypes: REQ-ENC-PA-REP
2012-11-11T14:45:39 Looking for PK-INIT(ietf) pa-data -- brian.empson/admin@REALM
2012-11-11T14:45:39 Looking for PK-INIT(win2k) pa-data -- brian.empson/admin@REALM
2012-11-11T14:45:39 Looking for ENC-TS pa-data -- brian.empson/admin@REALM
2012-11-11T14:45:39 Need to use PA-ENC-TIMESTAMP/PA-PK-AS-REQ
2012-11-11T14:45:39 sending 303 bytes to IPv4:192.168.72.10
2012-11-11T14:45:39 AS-REQ brian.empson/admin@REALM from IPv4:192.168.72.10 for kadmin/admin@REALM
2012-11-11T14:45:39 Client sent patypes: ENC-TS, REQ-ENC-PA-REP
2012-11-11T14:45:39 Looking for PK-INIT(ietf) pa-data -- brian.empson/admin@REALM
2012-11-11T14:45:39 Looking for PK-INIT(win2k) pa-data -- brian.empson/admin@REALM
2012-11-11T14:45:39 Looking for ENC-TS pa-data -- brian.empson/admin@REALM
2012-11-11T14:45:39 ENC-TS Pre-authentication succeeded -- brian.empson/admin@REALM using aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96
2012-11-11T14:45:39 ENC-TS pre-authentication succeeded -- brian.empson/admin@REALM
2012-11-11T14:45:39 AS-REQ authtime: 2012-11-11T14:45:39 starttime: unset endtime: 2012-11-11T15:45:39 renew till: unset
2012-11-11T14:45:39 Client supported enctypes: aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96, aes128-cts-hmac-sha1-96, des3-cbc-sha1, arcfour-hmac-md5, using aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96/aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96
2012-11-11T14:45:39 sending 717 bytes to IPv4:192.168.72.10
```

I wish I had more detailed logging messages, running kadmind in debug mode *seems* to *almost* work but it just kicks me back to the shell when I type in the correct password.

GSSAPI via LDAP doesn't work either, but I suspect it's because some parts of kerberos aren't working either:

```
root@rds0:~# ldapsearch -Y GSSAPI -H ldaps:/// -b "o=mybase" o=mybase
SASL/GSSAPI authentication started
ldap_sasl_interactive_bind_s: Other (e.g., implementation specific) error (80)
        additional info: SASL(-1): generic failure: GSSAPI Error: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information ()
root@rds0:~# ldapsearch -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -b "o=mybase" o=mybase
SASL/EXTERNAL authentication started
SASL username: gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external,cn=auth
SASL SSF: 0
# extended LDIF
<snip>
```

Would anyone be able to point me in the right direction?

Comment: LDAP needs to allow kadmind proper permissions to access and write to LDAP. Naively, you could start out by giving everybody all permissions to LDAP. If kadmind can then read/write to LDAP, that's your issue. If there's still a problem, then start looking at other issues (which are more than what I could say in this comment).